# how to validate oracle user credentials in pl-sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write a pl-sql procedure that will take the login/password parameters and return some information about user.

I'd prefer it to be the information about whether the user belongs to Admin group or not.

Where should I start? 
Should I use some procedures or try to obtain the objects directly from system tables?

Comment: by credentials you must specify log in technique or privileges access to some functionality or screens please be more explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Users with the **sysdba** and **sysoper** privilege can be retrieved from the view **v$pwfile_users**.